# laravel - input value, I want to create a loop after outputting

Tags: php, laravel

```
   public function store(StoreTransactionRequest $request)
{
    $transaction = Transaction::create($request->all());
   
    $transaction->C = $request->A - $transaction->B;
 
    $transaction->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('admin.transactions.index');
}
```

#A is the input value, I want to create a loop after outputting #C, I want to assign #C to #A to further subtract an input value,
to return 1 the result is:

- C= A -B
- D = C -B
- E = D -B
- .....

-sorry i'm not good at english

Comment: And what the problem?

Comment: #C is the result, I want to assign #C to a certain value, after having the results I want to continue to get #C - input is #B, it's a loop , #thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(StoreTransactionRequest $request)
    {
        $transaction = Transaction::create($request->all());
        $transaction->transaction_next = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month")); 
        $transaction->counter_u = $request->counter_new - $transaction->project->counter_new - $transaction->project->counter_dm;
        $transaction->price_fee = ($request->counter_new - $transaction->project->counter_new - $transaction->project->counter_dm) * $transaction->project->fee_dm;
        $transaction->save();
        
         $projects = Project::find($request->project_id);
         $projects->counter_new = $transaction->counter_new;
         $projects->update();
```

this code it works

Comment: This has no relation to the question you asked. There is no looping of the values.

Comment: I want to replace the above code into a loop, if I delete it, $projects->counter_new will not change and the next result will be wrong.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the loop, I think it's the if  function